# Polymer: changing the array and template using JQuery

Tags: polymer

I've established an array, like this:

```
<template>
  <ul id="iconContainer" style="list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
    <template repeat="{{icon in icons}}">
      <li class="flex icon-container"><app-icon label="{{icon.label}}" src="{{icon.src}}"></app-icon></li>
    </template>
  </ul>
</template>
<script>
  Polymer('app-grid', {
    ready: function() {
      this.icons = [];
      for(i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
        this.icons.push({label: 'Item ' + i, src: '*'});
      },
      iconChanged: function() {
        this.$.iconContainer.getElementsByTagName('template')[0].iterator_.updateIteratedValue();
      }
  });
</script>
```

And I'm getting frustrated on trying to find out how to alter this array from jquery on index.html as shown below to update the template.

```
<app-grid></app-grid>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).querySelector('app-grid').icons.push({label: 'foo', src: '*'});
</script>
```

This doesn't seem to work though.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need jquery for this. The `document.querySelector('app-grid')` works just fine to get the element.

Before poking around at element properties, the element needs to have upgraded. The `polymer-ready` event is your signal that all elements are upgraded:

```
document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function(e) {
  document.querySelector('app-grid').icons.push({label: 'foo', src: '*'});
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/wasafomesuba/1/edit